# The meaning of ",_" in python

Tags: python

What is the meaning of , _  in the following Pyhyhon code?

```
 file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File',
            "","All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)")
```

Comment: ```_``` is a variable name here. You can use any valid variable name. The function returns two instances. One is stored in ```file_name``` and another is in ```_```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the single underscore "\_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Comment: The comma means the function returns a sequence of two values.  `file_name` is assigned the first value, and `_` is assigned the second.

Answer (score 4):

`_` is a name for a variable like anything else, but typically used to indicate that it won't be used. Think of it as `file_name, some_useless_variable = ...`